# How many proposals does it take for the boy-oriented Gale-Shapley to terminate when all boys have identical preferences?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

In this Stable Marriage problem all boys have identical preferences. I was wondering how many proposals would it take to terminate this boy-orientated GS. (By boy-orientated I mean the boys are proposing)

I know the Gale-Shapley algorithm terminates after n(n-1)+1 proposals but is this the same for this question. And if it is can anyone justify it?

Thank you for the help/advice

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: That was my initial thought but it doesn't seem to match up. This may be because I am doing it wrong, i'm not sure. For a 2x2 it works but not for a 3x3.

Comment: For some reason you don't define what you mean by "boy-oriented". I'm going to guess it means the boys do the proposing.

Comment: Yes it does, I haven edited the question :)